# Как изменять параметры экземпляра другого класса?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Есть класс, атрибут экземпляра которого меняется во времени. Есть другой класс, метод которого должен, в зависимости от значения атрибута экземпляра первого класса, делать изменения с этим самым атрибутом. Как это реализовать?

```
from livewires import games
class A(games.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        super(A, self).__init__() 
        self.attribute = attribute
    def update(self):
        self.attribute += 1
class B(games.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(B, self).__init__() 
        self.object = obj
    def update(self):
        if self.object.attribute > 100:
            self.someonemetod()
    def someonemetod(self):
        self.object.attribute = 1
a = A(90)
b = B(a)
games.screen.add(a)
games.screen.add(b)
games.screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что экземпляр класса `B`  должен изменять атрибут экземпляра класса `A`? При этом экземпляры должны как-то независимо друг от друга параллельно функционировать, и экземпляр класса `B` следит за состоянием экземпляра класса `A`?